# Regex matching groups boost c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

[Noob Corner]

Hello,
I'm trying to catch a group with boost regex depending on the string that matched and I think I'm using a wrong way.

```
boost::regex expr(R"(:?(:?\busername *(\S*))|(:?\bserver *(\S*))|(:?\bpassword *(\S*)))");
std::vector<std::string > vec = { "server my.server.eu", "username myusername", "password mypassword" };

for (auto &elem : vec)
{
   if (boost::regex_match(elem, expr, boost::match_extra))
    {
         boost::smatch what;
         boost::regex_search(elem, what, expr);

         std::cout << "Match 1 (username) : " << what[1].str() << std::endl;
         std::cout << "Match 2 (server) : " << what[2].str() << std::endl;
         std::cout << "Match 3 (password) : " << what[3].str() << std::endl;
     }
}
```

I want something like :

```
server my.server.eu
```

> Match 1 (username) : NULL
>   Match 2 (server) : my.server.eu
>   Match 3 (password) : NULL

I searched on internet but I have not found clear answers regarding the identification of capturing groups.

Thanks

Comment: You meant to use `(?:`, not `(:?`, right? Sorry, your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: What is sure, your regex can be written as `expr(R"(\b(?:username *(\S*)|server *(\S*)|password *(\S*)))")`. When testing, I get `Match 1 (username) : // Match 2 (server) : my.server.eu // Match 3 (password) :`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that was that, I reversed the ? and the : 
This plus the named groups capture have resolved my issue.

Comment: Good, but you seem to be happy with the current answer. I will refrain from posting the code and my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have 6 and not 3 matching groups.

Your regular expression is organized in such a manner that the odd matching groups will match a key-value (i.e.: username myusername) while the even matching groups will match the actual value (i.e.: myusername).

So you have to look for groups 2, 4 and 6 to get the username, server and password values.